# Finding two specific substrings and adding them to a counter, then printing out the counter

Tags: python

I have an infile that contains fake coronavirus results (sex, age, height, weight, test results, zipcode)
I am trying to retrieve the amount of positive female and male cases and output it to a printline.
I am new to programming and i've tried for so long to get it to work but no luck, this is my current code

sample infile
M 87  66 133 - 33634
M 17  77 119 - 33625
M 63  57 230 - 33603
F 55  50 249 - 33646
M 45  51 204 - 33675

```
males = 0
females = 0
positivem = 0
positivef = 0
with open("/Users/newuser/Desktop/hw1data.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        words = line.lower().split()
        for word in words:
            if (word == "m"):
                males += 1
            elif (word == 'f'):
                females += 1
            else:
                males = males
                females = females
        for word in words:
            if ((word == 'm') and (word == '+')):
                positivem += 1
            elif ((word == 'f') and (word == '+')):
                positivef += 1
            else:
                positivem = positivem 
                positivef = positivef
            
print("{0} males have been tested and {1} females have been tested.".format(males,females))
print("Of those {0} males, {1} have tested positive.".format(males, positivem))
print("Of those {0} females, {1} have tested positive.".format(females, positive
```

Comment: Could you also attach input data sample?

Comment: I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: added it to post

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code a bit. You need to learn the basics of if...else statements.
Since the data occurs at a specific index in the list "words", you can directly use the indices to fetch them, you do not need to loop through the entire list.

Let me know if this code has any errors.

```
males = females = positivef = positivem = 0
with open("/Users/newuser/Desktop/hw1data.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        words = line.lower().split()
        if words[0]=='M':
            males+=1
            if words[4]=='+':
                positivem+=1
        else:
            females+=1
            if words[4]=='+':
                positivef+=1

print("{0} males have been tested and {1} females have been tested.".format(males,females))
print("Of those {0} males, {1} have tested positive.".format(males, positivem))
print("Of those {0} females, {1} have tested positive.".format(females, positivef))
```

Comment: it worked, yes that makes so much more sense. since the text file has a specific layout, it's easier to search it using specific index numbers.